# This resource can not be previewed at the moment. - CKAN

Tags: dataset, ckan

I’m running CKAN 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64).

I have uploaded a dataset to the CKAN instance. It has been uploaded successfully and can be downloaded as well. But when I try to preview the database I end up with below error.

> This resource can not be previewed at the moment.

When I click on the “Click here for more information”, It says

> Could not load preview: DataProxy returned an error (Request Error:
>   Backend did not respond after 10 seconds)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is that the data proxy (which is used to transform csv to
>   something that the data preview can understand) is a server on the
>   internet. Consequently the files you want to preview have to publicly
>   accessible from the internet as well. localhost is your own computer
>   which means that the dataproxy cannot access it. To solve this, wither put the file in the datastore using the datastorer or put the file on a server and provide the correct url.

.

> This happens because the data proxy which is used to transform the
>   data into something we can preview with recline needs the files to be
>   accessible from the internet. The best solution is to store the data
>   in the datastore and then the preview will work.

Extracted from [here](https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2013-July/005471.html) & [here](https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2013-June/005177.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get the same message as the title question:

> This resource can not be previewed at the moment.

But when you click on the “Click here for more information”, It says:

> Could not load preview: DataProxy returned an error (Data transformation failed. error: An error occured while connecting to the server: DNS lookup failed for URL: http:///dataset/c3ce226b-73bd-4b06-9d1b-ffea13d5f770/resource/580fb05f-6d86-4748-aac7-560b904a208f/download/foo.csv)

In this case, probably the **datapusher** plugin is not working. First follow the instructions for datapusher in CKAN manual. If you already did this or you installed CKAN from a package, check the CKAN configuration in production.ini (development.ini) file. A small check list to solve the problem:

- add datapusher in "ckan.plugins"
- set "ckan.site_url"
- set "ckan.datapusher.url"
- check Apache/nginx server logs (*/var/log/apache2/datapusher.*.log, /var/log/apache2/ckan_default*.log*)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was in my development.ini (or production.ini for you maybe) file where the lines for DataPusher's configuration were commented out with a # in the start of the line. Also, the ckan storage config line was also commented.

I uncommented those lines and it was solved.