# CKAN dataexplorer preview only works sometimes

Tags: ckan

Similar questions exist: [CKAN ERROR preview CSV , but OK for Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327516/ckan-error-preview-csv-but-ok-for-download)  / [This resource can not be previewed at the moment. - CKAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515007/this-resource-can-not-be-previewed-at-the-moment-ckan?rq=1)

---

Sometimes CSV preview is not available with error message "This resource view is not available at the moment." It tells me it's because the backend took longer than 10 seconds to respond.

But it works fine at other times. - Why would it be?

How can I make it work ALL the time?

Comment: Not sure what to try. Any suggestions please? DataStore seems working (tests work), but all our real datasets currently are not on our server, they are linked. It gives the error when I check during the day (Australia time) but when I try again later at night to early morning it is working.

Comment: @DRead I couldn't paste the error message because it is working right now, but the second link to similar question has the same error. But our site is accessible through internet, so that isn't the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datasets are linked (rather than datastore) then the backend it refers to is probably the proxy service jsonpdataproxy.appspot.com that OKF run on Google App Engine (but check that - I've not read that code for a while). That service comes with no guarantees. No doubt it is just too slow at busy times. But I think it may also be buggy and throw exceptions when reading particular files.

At data.gov.uk we run our own local proxy - [ckanext-datapreview](https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-datapreview) - using the files that we cache using ckanext-archiver. We don't support it, it is slightly different API to what vanilla recline uses, but the code is not long or difficult to read / adapt.